# Response mess up when curl Django url

Tags: python, django, curl

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_node(request, uid=None):
    resp = {
        'status': 0
    }
    return JsonResponse(resp)
```

Then I use `curl` to test it, which messed my terminal. But it works fine in browser.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Comment: The same without the gzip header?

Comment: Yes. Is there any chance Django's middleware added these bytes into the responses?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is because of my proxy configuration. Whenever `$http_proxy` variable is set, things go wrong.